# Change detection in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm used to using `tsc -w` to watch files for changes which will automatically compile them when a change is detected.  I am trying to start using angular-cli as a starter.  However to see changes, I have to stop the server process, build with `ng build`, (which rebuilds the *whole project*, not just the file that changed), and then serve it with `ng serve`.  There must be a better way!  I was also surprised that I could not easily find and change what `ng build` does, like I could for an npm command by looking in package.json.

Comment: I am just running ng serve and that is watching the files for me and refreshing the browser on file changes... except for stylesheet files for some reason

Comment: OK.  I should have been more specific to my setup.  I am actually running `node dist/server` instead of `ng build`, because I am using an express server (from [this article](https://javascriptrocks.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/express-with-angular-cli-in-5-minutes/)) instead of whatever angular-cli uses.  Either way, is there a way to see what is executed with `ng build`, so that I can replace the built in server with call to js file with express commands?

Comment: So maybe the better question is [how to replace angular-cli server with express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128352/how-to-replace-angular-cli-server-with-express)